# Javascript function stored in array vs in a variable

Tags: javascript, function, this

In this example why does pushing the function reference onto the array not change the <s>`scope`</s> `execution context` of `this` whereas assigning the function reference to a new variable does change the <s>`scope`</s> `execution context` of `this`?

```
(function() {
    function Car(year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    Car.prototype = {
        logYear: function() {
            console.log(this.year);
        }
    };

    var ford = new Car('Ford', 1999);

    ford.logYear();

    var cbs = [];

    cbs.push(ford.logYear);

    for(var x = 0; x < cbs.length; x++) {
        cbs[x](); // -> 1999 #1
        var callback = cbs[x];
        callback(); // -> undefined #2
    }
})()
```

Is this because the reference to the function in the array points to the original function on the `ford` object where `this` is still defined as the instance (#1) and the variable assignment changes the `this` to point to the wrapping `IIFE` block (#2)?

Is this a good pattern if I need to collect of bunch of methods like this from various objects and call them somewhere else?

How does this referential calling relate to examples like `console.error.bind(console)`?

Thanks!

***-- Update***

Thanks to [@Satyajeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35417632) for the nice explanation and clarification.

Typos & copying errors aside the reason I was asking this question in the first place is that I suspected what Satyajeet confirmed but an application I am working on does not reflect this behavior (or so I thought).

It turns out that in the application I am performing a similar process to the above code where I call `cbs.push(ford.logYear);`, adding multiple methods from different objects to an array.

At a point in the app I call all these methods and expect them to behave in the same way as when they are called in the <s>`execution context`</s> `scope` of the original object... and they do, because the values the methods interact with are not attached to `this`, they are captured in closures.

See example plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DIoZyYhwwUs9rjNvKWa4?p=info)

***-- Update 2***

Fixed usage of `execution context` and `scope` to be accurate for each part of the question/answer.

Comment: ` cbs[x](); // -> 1999 #1` will not print anything `Ford` or `1999`, it is printing `undefined`

Comment: JS is blocked scoped. So `this` will only change when called in a function. Your `cbs` array is in the same scope as `Car`

Comment: Actually your first console log is from you doing `ford.logYear();` you get undefined on all other log messages. So you are changing the scope of `this`, you are just misinterpreting the log messages

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ah, thanks! That's what I get for coding late and copypasta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring your late night copy paste mistake, and redefining your Car function to

```
function Car(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year
}
```

`#1` indeed more of a question about how **Array** works rather then about the **context** and **scope**(*`#2`)

You are calling a function inside an array, So **in javascript each element of an array is a property of that Array Object**. for example

```
var a = [];
a.push('Some value'); // a.0 is a property
```

but you just can not call `a.0` because in javascript **properties that begin with a digit cannot be referenced with dot notation, and must be accessed using bracket notation**

So when you are calling `cbx[0]()` it is essentially same as `cbx.0()`.
And here comes the role of **Scope** and **Execution context** in javascript. There are already many good articles and answers about Scope and Context in javascript. Just like [this](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/), So i think its not worth to explain all that here.

But fundamentally `this` is not defined till the execution of function(`this` depends on **Execution context** rather then scope).

So your `#1` will print `undefined` because `cbs[0]()` is equivalent to `cbs.0()`, And `this`(Execution context) is set to Array itself, which is `[function]`. (You only have a function inside it).

And your `#2` will also print `undefined` because Execution context is **global**(window object in case of browser) there.
Answer to your 3rd question is, You need to **Explicitly hard bind** Execution context to your function.

```
cbs.push(ford.logYear.bind(ford));
```

And your 4th question is i think just an another use case of ES5's **bind** method, Nothing special. It is normally used because browser implementations requires that execution context(this) of `console.error`   must be set to `window.console`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have a better understanding of `bind` now. It turns out the pattern I am using in the app I'm working on uses closures to maintain context when passing methods around, which is why adding methods to an array still works in my app's implementation. See my update to my question.

Comment: Ohh.. seems like you were having problem with Scope and i explained Context.. :)

Comment: I updated my question to fix my use of `execution context` and `scope` to be consistent and accurate when referring to `closures` vs `this`.